# How much can a MySQL 5.7 JSON datatype can hold

Tags: mysql, storage, quota, mysql-json

How much value / size can a MySQL 5.7 JSON datatype hold?

What are the limitations of the MySQL 5.7 JSON datatype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum size is 1GB per document, but the practical size should be about the same as (or within an order of magnitude of) what a typical row looks like.

The JSON datatype still uses row level locking, and thus it is probably good to keep documents to around the 1-2MB size or less.

Comment: Do you suggest me to i use this datatype for managing user details on my website on not? Website have more than one lakh users per day. Currently I am using mongo dB , so I think it's easy to convert to MySQL

Comment: The maximum table size (64TB) remains the same as it was prior.